Having one math symbol be in a different font from the others
So for one of my documents, I use \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} which gives a font I really like except for the summation symbol. I do like the summation symbol from the default font in LaTeX and wanted to know if there was any way to still use the mathematical font from the package I listed above but have the summation symbol generated in the default font?

Welcome to TeX.SE

Have fixed the \sum symbol from the default cmex font family, you can change the font name whatever you like, and the MWE is
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\makeatletter
\let\sum\relax%%make as null for safety purpose
\DeclareMathVersion{splmath}
\DeclareSymbolFont{splmathomx}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{splmathomx}{splmath}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{splmathomx}{"50}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

This is for test
\[
\sum+\prod=1
\]
\end{document}



I swear, I have no idea what is going on in that preamble, but what I do know is that it works. Not all heroes wear capes. THANK YOU

@GinoGamboni Thanks for your kind words

@MadyYuvi Not really correct, sorry.

@egreg Yes, just now saw your post, it's really nice, clean and neat, I should improve a lot and kindly support me as always

Before redefining a command, it’s very important to know what it does. If you run LaTeX on
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\show\sum

in interactive mode, you'll be presented with
> \sum=macro:
->\DOTSI \sumop \slimits@ .

and you see that it's \sumop that needs to be redefined. Adding \show\sumop would output
> \sumop=\mathchar"13CD.

You now go to fontmath.ltx to collect the relevant information related to \sum and deploy it here; the symbol font's name has to be changed, of course.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{"50}

\begin{document}

This is for test
\[
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2
\]

\end{document}


Just redefining \sum as proposed in another answer would have unwanted consequences:

\DOTSI is necessary for correct choice of ellipsis dots;
\slimits@ will do the right thing based on the sumlimits or nosumlimits options passed to amsmath.

Note that newtxmath automatically loads amsmath, which already (re)defines \sum in a similar way; newtxmath has the advantage of coming later and, since it changes a lot in the math setup, it can use a more sensible name than \sum@ of amsmath.
